# Ruby Serialize and DeSerialize Struct

Tags: ruby, serialization, struct

I'm trying to serialize an S3 Object so that I can deserialize at a later time. Deserialization is failing to grab the Object's class and is not grouping the object's variables. Here's my current code:

```
require 'yaml'
def serialize_array_of_objects(array, filename)
  unless array.empty?
    File.open(filename, "w+") do |f|
      array.each { |element|
        serialized_object = YAML::dump(element)
        f.write(serialized_object)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the contents of the file (redacted):

```
--- !ruby/struct:Aws::S3::Types::Object
key: file1.csv
last_modified: 2019-03-24 17:24:41.000000000 Z
etag: '"REDACTED"'
size: 41248
storage_class: STANDARD
owner:
--- !ruby/struct:Aws::S3::Types::Object
key: file2.csv
last_modified: 2019-04-24 15:30:41.000000000 Z
etag: '"REDACTED"'
size: 33527
storage_class: STANDARD
owner:
```

To deserialize the objects I'm using this code:

```
def serialized_file_to_array(filename)
  array = []
  File.open(filename, "r").each { |line|
    array << YAML::load(line)
  }
  return array
end
```

My problem is that the object get's distorted on load. Here's the array now:

```
[nil, {"key"=>"file1.csv"}, {"last_modified"=>2019-03-24 17:24:41 UTC}, {"etag"=>"\"REDACTED\""}, {"size"=>41248}, {"storage_class"=>"STANDARD"}, {"owner"=>nil}, nil, {"key"=>"file2.csv"}, {"last_modified"=>2019-04-24 15:30:41 UTC}, {"etag"=>"\"REDACTED\""}, {"size"=>33527}, {"storage_class"=>"STANDARD"}, {"owner"=>nil}]
```

I need to be able to pull the object key values in the deserialized version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you dump *objects* resulting in several lines in the `yaml` file, but you load back *lines* deserializing *lines*. Each line does not obviously contain the whole object, that’s why you get an array hashes (one per line) back.

You need to collect lines until the new object marker is there *or* to read the whole file content, split it into objects with e. g. regular expression and load split objects.

The first approach would be like:

```
File.readlines(FILE).
    each_with_object([[], []]) do |line, (inner_acc, outer_acc)|
  if line.start_with?('---')
    outer_acc << YAML.load(inner_acc.join) unless inner_acc.empty?
    inner_acc.clear << line
  else
    inner_acc << line
  end
end.tap do |inner_acc, outer_acc|
  break outer_acc << YAML.load(inner_acc.join) # last chunk
end
```

With regular expression, it should be even simpler.